# byte[]をMatに変換したい

Tags: c#, visual-studio, opencv, kinect

VisualStudio2019でC#を使ってKinectから送られてくる、byte型配列の画像データをOpenCVのMatに変換したいです。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: VS2015での例ですが、これ [OpenCvSharp3 ＋ Kinect v2](http://www.kirurobo.com/2016/02/opencvkinectv2.html) にソースがあり、参考になるかも。

Comment: 変換することは目的ではないはずです。変換した後どう使うのか、それによって変換の仕方も異なってきます。例えばopencvとはどれを指しているのでしょうか？ kunifさんはOpenCvSharp3をあげていますが質問者さんが使用環境を明確にする必要があります。

Comment: Emgu CVの記事はこちらが該当しそうです。[Kinect (ColorFrame) to Emgu Image](http://www.emgu.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=5205)